# Music visualization is not working in animation nodes

Tags: animation-nodes

I am creating a music visualizer using animation nodes.

The music visualizer do the same as the music visualizer of animation nodes (templates) but it has an extra motion (bending) I did by a loop,the problem is that all the frequencies bend the same increment and not based on the frequencies.

I don't know if that a bug or something I did wrong,here is the bend portion:

[image: bend]

The rest of the animation work without any problems but this doesn't.

So what Am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: I'm not at home atm so I can't test the file. (will do it later) Did you use the Object Instancer node to create the other objects? if yes, maybe you have to check "Deep Copy"?

Comment: good, I'll write a more in-depth answer when I'm at home :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you used the Object Instancer without making deep copies.
Making a "Deep Copy" means that each individual object will have its own mesh data. Otherwise all instances will share the same mesh data block. So when you change one of them you'll change all objects.

Your loop essentially changed the mesh on all objects multiple times.

Maybe this .gif explains better what "deep copy" means:

[image]